# How to change value of a property of a dynamic object in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I call a stored procedure from my code and it returns a

```
 IEnumerable<dynamic> data
```

with 3 properties

I would like to be able to modify one of a value of the data var for example

```
data[2].ID = 6687687
```

Do you know how to do this please?

Answer (score 2):

You can access individual elements by using the `ElementAt` method like this:

```
data.ElementAt(2).ID = 6687687;
```

However, this is not efficient since it will iterate through the enumerable until it reaches the required index. And sometimes the enumerable that you get will execute some query every time your enumerate it. This means that you will get new objects every time you enumerate it (e.g. via `ElementAt`).

A better way is to convert the enumerable to a list like this:

```
var list = data.ToList();
```

And then access the elements by index like this:

```
list[2].ID = 6687687;
```

Comment: thanks for answer! but it displays trigger error that informs me that  the number of args is uncorrect for calling méthod 'System.Object SetValue(System.String, System.Object, Boolean)

Comment: Are you sure that the underlying type supports setting the `ID` property as an integer?

Comment: and I would like to be able to change value of a property wathever the type of the property

Comment: Can you provide more information about the underlying type?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
var lItem = data.ElementAt(2);
lItem.ID = 6687687;
```

However note, that this can have a bad runtime performance when used to access many different indexes and the IEnumerable has no "simple" list object as a basis.